# ¿Cómo sumar dos matrices en ruby?

Tags: ruby, matrices

Si tengo dos matrices NxM, ¿cómo le puedo hacer para sumarlas? Ya sea solo sumar los datos de una matriz o los de ambas.

En java lo hago así:

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    for(j=0; j < m; j++){
        sumaA += A[i][j];
        sumaB += B[i][j];
    }
}

sumaT = sumaA + sumaB;
```

Al hacer esto en ruby me da este error:

> `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)`

Comment: Gracias a todos los que contestaron!
Lo solucioné con los mismos dos for y para sumarlas usé `C[i][j]=(A[i][j]).to_i+(B[i][j]).to_i`
Solo tuve que poner el `.to_i`

Comment: Si pudiste resolver tu problema con alguna de las respuestas, puedes marcar como correcta la que corresponda. Saludos

Comment: @Betsadi Utilizar `for` en el lenguaje ruby esta desaconsejado como una mala practica (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blame/master/README.md#L929). Siempre deben usarse los  Enumeradores como `mi_array.each`. Para tu caso existen mejores formas de hacerlo en Ruby. Echa un vistazo a lo que puse adicionalmente en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Tanto tu error `String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)` como el comentario que pusiste de que te imprime 123456123456 es por lo mismo, estás usando datos `String` en vez de `Fixnum` en las sumas y eso lo arreglas llamando `.to_i` en tu `String`. Como muestra un ejemplo:

```
2.2.5 :005 > 1 + '2' # no se puede sumar Fixnum y String
TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
        from (irb):5:in `+'
        from (irb):5
2.2.5 :007 > '1' + '2' # al sumar 2 String, los concatena
 => "12" 
2.2.5 :006 > 1 + 2 # al sumar 2 Fixnum... los suma
 => 3 
2.2.5 :008 > 1 + '2'.to_i # como deberías resolverlo
 => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo estas dos matrices:

```
a = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]
b = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]
```

Podemos obtener el total de los valores que las componen de la siguiente forma:

```
(a+b).flatten.sum
# => 42
```

Como funciona:

```
(a+b) # concatena las dos matrices
# => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
.flatten # descompone las matrices en un array plano
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
.sum # Calcula el total de los valores de un array
# => 42
```

*Nota* Esto esta probado con Ruby 2.4.0

Si tienes una version de Ruby mas antigua puede que mi codigo no te funcione. En tal caso, prueba con:

```
(a+b).flatten.inject(:+)
```

#### Actualizacion

Esto funciona cuando el contenido de las matrices son numeros. Como apunta @AlterLagos en su respuesta, tu error indica que estas operando sobre `String`. En tal caso, convertir el contenido a `Fixnum` solucionara tu problema:

```
(a+b).flatten.map { |x| x.to_i }.inject(:+)
# => 42
```

Dependiendo de tu version de Ruby puede que tambien puedas utilizar la version reducida:

```
(a+b).flatten.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
# => 42
```

Comment: El `.sum` no me lo reconoce así que intente con `(a+b).flatten.inject(:+)` y así solo me imprime los numeros reccoridos. O sea imprime algo como 123456123456

Comment: @Betsadi Que version de Ruby utilizas? En http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0 se utiliza `1.9.3` (se puede comprobar tecleando `RUBY_VERSION`) y con el metodo `inject(:+)` funciona correctamente.

Comment: @Betsadi Puedes colocar en tu pregunta el contenido de las matrices? Tal vez sean `String` en lugar de numeros como apunta @AlterLagos. Prueba con `(a+b).flatten.map { |x| x.to_i }.inject(:+)` que convertira todas las String a Fixnum.